# Is it possible to map Thingsboard configuration files to host file system when running inside Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, configuration, docker-volume, thingsboard

I have Thingsboard installed in Docker in Ubuntu.
The compose file maps 2 volumes to the host system, the data and logs directories, and that works fine.

I wanted to do the same with the conf directory, to be able to modify some configuration and environment variables values in the thingsboard.yml and .conf files, and avoid having to recreate the containers each time I change something.

I've tried do it the same way it is done for the data and log directories in the docker-compose.yml:

```
> volumes:
> - /ThingsboardDocker/conf:/usr/share/thingsboard/conf
```

... but it throws this error when creating the containers:

```
/usr/bin/start-tb.sh: line 25: /usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf: No such file or directory  mytb_1       | /usr/bin/install-tb.sh: line 45: /usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf: No such file or directory
```

For the data and logs directories works fine, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work for the configuration files.

What could be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Bind mounts from the host _always_ hide the data that was originally present in the image; Docker never copies anything back to the host for you (some image setup code knows how to do this but it's not an out-of-the-box default).  If you mount an empty directory over the config files, the config files will be missing inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The item you currently use is `bind mount`, what I suggest is to use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), this could pop up the data in container to a special place on host. A minimal example as next, you could customize it to meet your requirement:

**20211008/docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    volumes:
      - export_data:/etc/nginx/conf.d

volumes:
  export_data:
```

After the container start, e.g. has the name `20211008_app_1`, then we could use next to get the path of `export_data`:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/20211008$ docker inspect 20211008_app_1 | grep export_data
                "20211008_export_data:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw"
                "Name": "20211008_export_data",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/20211008_export_data/_data",
```

Here, `/var/lib/docker/volumes/20211008_export_data/_data` means the host directory which you could find the contents of `/etc/nginx/conf.d` in container:

**On host:**

```
root@shubuntu1:/var/lib/docker/volumes/20211008_export_data/_data# ls
default.conf
```

**In container:**

```
root@shubuntu1:~# docker exec -it 20211008_app_1 ls /etc/nginx/conf.d
default.conf
```